# How do I update Tesseract on PA?

Tags: tesseract, python-tesseract, pythonanywhere

I'm developing an app which uses Pytesseract and I'm hosting it on PA. Tesseract is preinstalled
but apparently the version is old (3.04) when I run my code I get error:

`"TSV output not supported. Tesseract >= 3.05 required"`

How can I upgrade it since I can't use `sudo apt` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The latest version of Tesseract is not available on PythonAnywhere yet. It should be available with the next system image later this spring.

Comment: Do you have exact date by any chance ?

Comment: I'm assuming you're an insider.

Comment: No exact date. Follow blog.pythonanywhere.com